# El sitio web al que vas a acceder es engañoso

Tags: php, web, google-chrome

> Por que google chrome dice que mi página es peligrosa?

La página no tiene contenido malo, no es una página phishing....

¿Alguien sabe como solucionar este problema?

> Solo para acceder a la página verifica si estas logeado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Utilizas algún certificado TLS? Puedes mandar una solicitud a google https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/?hl=en

Comment: Es una página gratuita en hostinger apuntado a un dominio.

Comment: Puedes revisar tu sitio en https://www.virustotal.com/es/  y reportarlo al link que te dí

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema puede estar causando el login, lo que puedes hacer es crear un sub dominio y subir ahí y verás que google no lo detectará como pagina engañoso.

Answer (score 3):

**Esto puede ocurrir porque tu servidor/hosting/sitio web, pudo haber sido infectado con algun tipo de *Malware*.**

**Sin embargo, aunque no existe una solucion inmediata que lo arregle todo, debes tener en cuenta que los navegadores, siempre revisan la lista de Google Safe Browsing, para poder determinar si un sitio es malicioso**

*Revisa tu sitio con la herramienta de chequeo de Google Safe Browsing: [Aqui](https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/safebrowsing/diagnostic/?hl=es)*

*Tambien, puedes guiarte con el siguiente articulo de Google acerca de la pirateria de Sitios WEB [Aqui](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/hacked/)*

Comment: En el sitio de chequeo Google te indica, porque ha puesto tu sitio web en la lista de sitios maliciosos.

Comment: P.D. Este proceso de "desbaneo", puede tardar hasta 72 horas.